# Subset dataframe with inclusive cutoff rather than exclusive

Tags: r, subset

This should be a fairly simple solution but I haven't for the life of me been able to figure out how to solve.

I have a column containing cumulative sums of proportions based on a certain combination of factor levels for my data,

eg.: 0.34, 0.57, 0.66, 0.68, 0.73, 0.81, 0.90, 0.97, 0.98, 0.99,

then the data moves to the next combination of factors and resets the cumulative sum,

eg.: 0.27, 0.29, 0.38, 0.56, 0.78, 0.94, 0.96, 0.97, 0.98 etc.

I calculated this with the following, for combinations of levels of two factors:

```
DF$CumSum <-ave(DF$Proportion, DF$Factor1, DF$Factor2, FUN = "cumsum")
```

I want to set a cutoff to subset my data at 0.95 so that I exclude the rows for the increasingly small proportions past this threshold, since the data was arranged in order of proportion before being cumulatively summed. The problem is if I have a set of proportions such as the following,

eg.: 0.58, 0.97, 0.98, 0.99,

then by thresholding at 0.95 I am excluding, in this case 0.39 of proportions, which is a lot, and I would be left with,

eg.: 0.58

Although 0.97 exceeds the threshold (0.95), the previous row is below the threshold (0.58). I would expect any subsequent rows after the first row above 0.95 for the factor level combination to be excluded.

Is there a way to use a different subsetting technique so that in cases like this, the data would be subsetted inclusive of this value? eg. the output would be: 0.58, 0.97 without increasing my cutoff threshold. I have tried implementing an ifelse statement inside of a for loop without success. This is what I came up with:

```
Threshold <- 0.95

for(i in 2:length(DF$Index)) {

    DF[i] <- ifelse(DF$CumSum[i-1] < Threshold & DF$CumSum[i] >= Threshold, 
    DF[-i,], DF[i])

  }
```

Example data:

```
Index   Factor1 Factor2 Proportion  CumSum
 1        A        A       0.3       0.3
 2        A        A       0.2       0.5
 3        A        A       0.1       0.6
 4        A        A       0.05      0.65
 5        A        A       0.03      0.68
 6        A        A       0.01      0.69
 7        A        B       0.4       0.4
 8        A        B       0.3       0.7
 9        A        B       0.2       0.9
 10       A        B       0.05      0.95
 11       A        B       0.03      0.98
 12       A        B       0.002     0.982
 13       A        B       0.001     0.983
 14       B        A       0.35      0.35
 15       B        A       0.2       0.55
 16       B        A       0.12      0.67
 17       B        A       0.06      0.73
 18       B        A       0.04      0.77
 19       B        B       0.6       0.6
 20       B        B       0.3       0.9
 21       B        B       0.08      0.98
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally understood that you only want to exclude if prev value is more than 0.95. the below should work:

```
DF$CumSum <- ave(DF$Proportion, DF$Factor1, DF$Factor2, FUN = "cumsum")
do.call(rbind, by(DF, paste(DF$Factor1, DF$Factor2), function(subDF) {
    subDF[c(TRUE, (dplyr::lag(subDF$CumSum) <= 0.95)[-1]),]
}))

#       Index Factor1 Factor2 Proportion CumSum
#A A.1      1       A       A       0.30   0.30
#A A.2      2       A       A       0.20   0.50
#A A.3      3       A       A       0.10   0.60
#A A.4      4       A       A       0.05   0.65
#A A.5      5       A       A       0.03   0.68
#A A.6      6       A       A       0.01   0.69
#A B.7      7       A       B       0.40   0.40
#A B.8      8       A       B       0.30   0.70
#A B.9      9       A       B       0.20   0.90
#A B.10    10       A       B       0.05   0.95
#B A.14    14       B       A       0.35   0.35
#B A.15    15       B       A       0.20   0.55
#B A.16    16       B       A       0.12   0.67
#B A.17    17       B       A       0.06   0.73
#B A.18    18       B       A       0.04   0.77
#B B.19    19       B       B       0.60   0.60
#B B.20    20       B       B       0.30   0.90
#B B.21    21       B       B       0.08   0.98
```

## data:

```
Df <- read.table(text="Index   Factor1 Factor2 Proportion  CumSum
1        A        A       0.3       0.3
2        A        A       0.2       0.5
3        A        A       0.1       0.6
4        A        A       0.05      0.65
5        A        A       0.03      0.68
6        A        A       0.01      0.69
7        A        B       0.4       0.4
8        A        B       0.3       0.7
9        A        B       0.2       0.9
10       A        B       0.05      0.95
11       A        B       0.03      0.98
12       A        B       0.002     0.982
13       A        B       0.001     0.983
14       B        A       0.35      0.35
15       B        A       0.2       0.55
16       B        A       0.12      0.67
17       B        A       0.06      0.73
18       B        A       0.04      0.77
19       B        B       0.6       0.6
20       B        B       0.3       0.9
21       B        B       0.08      0.98", header=TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks @chinsoon12! I am not sure I fully understand the purpose of using median but in this case, rather than a single sequence I have a series of sequences in a column based on combinations of two factors. How would I implement this code to take the median within factor levels? I calculated CumSum with the following:  DF$CumSum <-ave(DF$Proportion, DF$Factor1, DF$Factor2, FUN = "cumsum")

Comment: Sample data is now provided in my original question. Thanks! :)

Comment: unfortunately not. If it were working as expected, than row 21 would not be excluded from the dataframe. If it were functioning properly, I would it expect to exclude only rows: 11, 12, 13. Row 21 would not be excluded because although it exceeds the threshold (0.95), the previous row is below the threshold (0.90). I would expect any subsequent rows after the first row above 0.95 for the factor level combination to be excluded. Does that make sense? Thanks again!

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I am attempting but I get the following error when I use your code: Error in attr(x, "tsp") <- c(1, NROW(x), 1) : 
  attempt to set an attribute on NULL
Called from: hasTsp(x)
Browse[1]> Q

Comment: are there any groups with only 1 row? will need to know exact row count for each group to identify the problem

Comment: All factor1, factor2 combinations have 173 rows

Comment: hard to identify the cause of the error without the actual data. you might want to do some printing within the function to see each `subDF`

Comment: I got it working. I forgot to substitute one of my variables into the equation. The issue is though that it does the same thing as subsetting by threshold. It still cuts off any rows with value greater than the threshold, even if the previous value is below the threshold.

Comment: can you post some examples?

Comment: I used it on the test data I provided exactly as you have written it and which you built the function for. It still removed rows 10 and 21, which is different to the result you provided in your answer, which maintained those rows and removed only rows 11:13. Very strange.

Comment: ok i know why. i edited the code to specify the namspace for `lag`

Comment: sorry about the missing `dplyr::` earlier

Comment: No problem really. I would have never been able to solve this issue without your help!